# Fix the size of details section in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I m using crystal report in vs2010.

I m generating Tax invoice report..in that, details section size is dynamic.
i.e. depend on number of records, it changes. so if i've 10 records the report view is full page that is k ..but if i have 2 records in details sections, then whole page footer section getting stick to details page..so whole alignment is getting change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the print at bottom of page property in the select expert. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1)First of all fix height of detail section by right click on detail section ->section expert->New Page Before checked->beside button of (x+2) write formula(**Suppose you want 7 records in per page and further on another page**  -> IF Remainder (RecordNumber, 8) = 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE

2)under detail section (suppose section3) is your detail section then leave report section blank with needed space and else for footer put it in page footer .. i think this will solve your problem.. mine is solved..

Answer (score 0):

In my case in the New Page Before checked add:

```
IF Remainder (RecordNumber, 18) = 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
```